# How to use Latitud and Longitud as a variable in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an SQLITE3 database where I defined lat and long as text.
I need to use those lat, and long as the final destination in a map.
The intent is defined as:

```
      if(locationMap != null){

        Intent  theIntent = new Intent(getApplication(), displayMap.class);

        theIntent.putExtra("_Id",          locationMap.get("_Id")); 
        theIntent.putExtra("locCode",      locationMap.get("locCode")); 
        theIntent.putExtra("locDesc",      locationMap.get("locDesc")); 
        theIntent.putExtra("locLat",       locationMap.get("locLat")); 
        theIntent.putExtra("locLong",      locationMap.get("locLong")); 
        theIntent.putExtra("locTelephone", locationMap.get("locTelephone")); 
        theIntent.putExtra("locComments",  locationMap.get("locComments")); 


        startActivity(theIntent); // display map with coordinates
      }
```

In the next activity I recover the values in the On create method:

```
  // Parameters 
  String locCode      = i.getStringExtra("locCode");
  String locDesc      = i.getStringExtra("locDesc");
  String locLat       = i.getStringExtra("locLat");
  String locLong      = i.getStringExtra("locLong");
  String locTelephone = i.getStringExtra("locTelephone");
  String locComments  = i.getStringExtra("locComments");

  String Text = "Current location is: " +
  i.getStringExtra("locLat");
  Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),Text,
  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  System.out.println("locCode: " + locCode);
  System.out.println("LocDesc: " + locDesc);
  System.out.println("LocLat:  " + locLat);
  System.out.println("LocLong: " + locLong);
  System.out.println("LocTelephone: " + locTelephone);
  System.out.println("LocComment: " + locComments);

  getLocation(ORIGIN);
  setContentView(R.layout.map);
  if (mLastSelectedMarker != null && mLastSelectedMarker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
      // Refresh the info window when the info window's content has changed.
      mLastSelectedMarker.showInfoWindow();
  }
  setUpMapIfNeeded();
```

}

I need to use those locLat and Loclong instead of the numbers:

```
public class displayMap extends FragmentActivity implements
OnMarkerClickListener,
OnInfoWindowClickListener {

    public LatLng ORIGIN = new LatLng(34.02143074239393, -117.61349469423294);
    public LatLng DESTINY = new LatLng(34.022365269080886, -117.61271852999926);

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Marker mDestiny;
    private Marker mOrigin;
    private Marker mLastSelectedMarker; // keeps track of last selected marker
```

I've tried transforming the text to double and It won't allow me to.

I've tried many solutions I found on stack overflow, but no luck yet.

I appreciate any help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you are new user here, let me tell you that you should accept an answer here if you get the solution of your problem to let others know what worked for you. To accept an answer just click on the Right Tick sign on the left side of answer which ever you want to select.

Comment: I did it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the latitude and longitude from String to double to use in `new LatLng();`

```
double latitude = Double.parseDouble(locLat);
double longitude = Double.parseDouble(locLong);
```

and then,

```
public LatLng ORIGIN = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need cast them into double. As GPRathour says.

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of Lat Long Text to REAL in your SQL Lite,
when inserting values use this

```
 values.put(Latitude_Column, ORIGIN.latitude);
 values.put(Longitude__Column,ORIGIN.longitude);
```

And for retrieving values

LatLng origin = new  LatLng(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(Latitude_Column)),cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(Longitude__Column)));

No need to parsing values